# Replace template parameter list with variadic parameter

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

Can someone help with how I can replace a list of template types with a variadic template parameter and create unique pointers of each type within the class.

The problem is I have a class

```
template <typename TA, typename TB1, typename TB2>
class Foo
```

which I want to extend to more than 2 `TB` types as such

```
template <typename TA, typename ... TB>
class Foo
```

Full example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Some concrete types
struct A
{
    A(int a) : a_(2*a){}
    void execute() const { std::cout << "A: " << a_ << "\n"; }
    int a_;
};
struct B1
{
    B1(int a, double b) : a_(a), b_(b){}
    void execute() const { std::cout << "B1: " << a_ << ", " << b_ << "\n"; }
    int a_; double b_;
};
struct B2
{
    B2(int a, double b) : a_(a*a), b_(b*b){}
    void execute() const { std::cout << "B2: " << a_ << ", " << b_ << "\n"; }
    int a_; double b_;
};

// Now declare a templated class
template <typename TA, typename TB1, typename TB2>
class Foo
{
private:
  // A unique pointer to each template type
  std::unique_ptr<TA>  m_a{};
  std::unique_ptr<TB1> m_b1{};
  std::unique_ptr<TB2> m_b2{};
public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;
  
  void initialise(int a, double b)
  {
    m_a  = std::make_unique<TA>(a);
    m_b1 = std::make_unique<TB1>(a, b);
    m_b2 = std::make_unique<TB2>(a, b);
  }

  void execute() const
  {
    m_a->execute();
    m_b1->execute();
    m_b2->execute();
  }
};

int main(int, char**)
{
  // Use templated class
  Foo<A,B1,B2> foo;
  foo.initialise(5, 3.14159);
  foo.execute();
  return 0;
}
```

Within the class `Foo` I declare, instantiate and use unique pointers to each of the types `TB1` and `TB2`. With just 2 template parameters, I can easily do this. However, I don't know how to do this with a variadic template parameter.

Essentially I would like to change `Foo` to look like this:

```
template <typename TA, typename ... TB>
class Foo
{
private:
  // A unique pointer to each template type
  std::unique_ptr<TA>  m_a{};
  // TODO: Declare list or tuple of unique pointers to each of the types in TB ...
public:
  Foo() = default;
  ~Foo() = default;
  
  void initialise(int a, double b)
  {
    m_a  = std::make_unique<TA>(a);
    // TODO: Instantiate the list/tuple of unique pointers
  }

  void execute() const
  {
    m_a->execute();
    // TODO: Call execute on the list/tuple of unique pointers
  }
};
```

The parts that I have labelled TODO are the ones I don't know (even if this can be done at all).

Some notes

- The `TB` classes are distinct and do not necessarily have a common base class
- The `TB` classes do not have a default constructor.
- We can assume that the `TB` classes have a non-default constructor with the same signature.

Of course I'm also open to a completely different approach which allows me to have up to 6 TB classes without much code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something along these lines, perhaps (not tested):

```
template <typename TA, typename ... TB>
class Foo
{
private:
  std::unique_ptr<TA>  m_a{};
  std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<TB>...> m_bs;

public:
  void initialise(int a, double b)
  {
    m_a  = std::make_unique<TA>(a);
    std::apply([&](std::unique_ptr<TB>&... p) {
        (void(p = std::make_unique<TB>(a, b)), ...);
      },
      m_bs);
  }

  void execute() const
  {
    m_a->execute();
    std::apply([&](std::unique_ptr<TB>&... p) {
        (void(p->execute()), ...);
      },
      m_bs);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Just had to add `const` to the parameter pack in the second lambda because the `execute` method in `Foo` is `const`.